# check if filename is like string in php for displaying images

Tags: php, image

I am trying to get all images from a folder with php. It works fine. Now i wanna check if a certain image exists, and if so don't display it.

This is my basic code with works fine:

```
  foreach (glob("Bilder/Spectrum/*.png") as $filename) {
  $filenameDienst = explode("_", $filename);
  echo "<a href='Dienste?d=".$filenameDienst[1]."#tabs-2'> <img class='loopimage' src='".$filename."'> </a>";
  }
```

Now i wanna check for the image name "MB_default_Spectrum.png" and if it exists don't display it.

I have tried this:

```
 foreach (glob("Bilder/Spectrum/*.png") as $filename) {
 $filenameDienst = explode("_", $filename);
 if ($filename != "MB_default_Spectrum.png") {
echo "<a href='Dienste?d=".$filenameDienst[1]."#tabs-2'> <img class='loopimage' src='".$filename."'> </a>";
}
 }
```

But it did not work.. it is still displaying. What is wrong here? Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($filename);` - is it really, what you believe?

Comment: .. totally forgot to check that. Was so sure about the filename. Still a beginner. Thank you. You can post it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob` returns an array of the *paths* matching the given pattern, not just the filenames. Looking at your code, the condition should then be:

```
if ($filename != "Bilder/Spectrum/MB_default_Spectrum.png")
```

Also, I personally prefer the following code (I find it cleaner):

```
$results = glob('path/to/dir/*.png');
foreach ($results as $filename) 
    // Skip specific file
    if ($filename === 'path/to/dir/secretNuclearLaunchCodesAsImage.png')
        continue;
    echo $filename
}
```